# Optimizar la respuesta de un servicio en una Api-Rest con Spring Boot

Tags: java, api, spring, spring-boot

Buen día, actualmente me encuentro desarrollando una api rest con Spring Boot ::        (v1.5.9.RELEASE) para controlar el manejo de una tabla llamada Expediente, la cual persiste con otras entidades,

[image: Tabla Expediente]

El controlador para llamar al servicio es el siguiente:

`@RestController
public class ExpedientController {
    @Autowired
    protected ExpedientService expedientService;
    @Autowired
    protected ExpedientSubserviceService expedientSubserviceService;
    protected UserService userService;
    protected ObjectMapper mapper;`

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/expedient/saveOrUpdate",method = RequestMethod.POST)
public RestResponse saveOrUpdate(@RequestBody String expedientJSON) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
    this.mapper= new ObjectMapper();
    Expedient expedient=this.mapper.readValue(expedientJSON,Expedient.class);
    this.expedientService.save(expedient);
    String message = Integer.toString(expedient.getId())+" "+Integer.toString(expedient.assured.getId());
    return new RestResponse(HttpStatus.OK.value(), message);

}
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/expedient/getAll", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<Expedient> getAll() {
    return this.expedientService.findAllByDeletedAt(0);
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/api/expedient/delete", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void deleteExpedient(@RequestBody String expedientJson) throws Exception {
    this.mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    Expedient expedient = this.mapper.readValue(expedientJson, Expedient.class);

    if (expedient.getId()==0) {
        throw new Exception("El id esta nulo");
    }
    this.expedientService.delete(expedient.getId());
}
```

El Json de la consulta es grande por la cantidad de objetos que persisten entre ellos, ¿Es recomendado que se hagan consultas separadas sin necesidad de traer en el json toda la información de las entidades persistidas? O existe algún método de compresión que se pueda utilizar.

Comment: To te recomendaría irte por [tag:graphql-java], o si tu sistema ya está implementado por [tag:graphql-spqr], así obtendrás la flexibilidad de [tag:graphql] y te evitarás crear un DTO para cada consulta que necesites de un subconjunto de datos de tu objeto principal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola hay depende mucho de la arquitectura del servicio y como seria consumido pero podes hacer varias cosas:

1. Diseñar un esquema de DTO's para mostrar menos datos de tus entidades , es decir Ids y solo informacion enscencial.
2. Activar la compresion Gzip en tu apliacion [link](https://www.callicoder.com/configuring-spring-boot-application/)
3. Si estos datos van a ser consumidos denttro de una grilla o mostrarlo en una web podes habilitar la paginación extendiendo de de la interfaz **PagingAndSortingRepository** en tus repositorios y con esto vas a traer los registros paginados aliviando mucho la consulta.

Ejemplo Paginación:

```
public interface ExpedientRepository extends  PagingAndSortingRepository<Expedient ,Long> {
}
```

Espero que te haya servido de ayuda

Saludos.

Comment: Gracias después de un tiempo llegue a la conclusión de que es necesario paginar las consultas y optimizar las relaciones , Ya que es demasiada información para consumir en una query. Diste en el punto.Ya había usado Gzip y mejoro un 35% el tiempo de carga pero eso me trajo otros problemas. Pero ya resolví , spring es un framework poderoso con una curva de aprendizaje muy pronunciada.